# multiple windows in vim at Mac

Tags: vim

In Linux, opening multiple windows in vim could use "ctrl + w + =" to make equal size of all windows. But this doesn't seem to work in my MacBook (with VIM version 8.0.642). 
Does anyone have solution? It is really annoying that if I open two windows, one has much bigger window size than the other.

Comment: It works just the same. Try again.

Comment: In some cases, what is "Ctrl" in other OSs would be the command key (⌘) in Mac. So try `⌘ + W + =` if you haven't already.

Comment: no, "⌘ + W + =" would not work because in Mac "⌘ + W" is closing the tab(window).

Comment: actually, "ctrl+w" to switch in different windows works for me, but the "ctrl+w+=" is not working. Mine is MacBookPro 2017 with touch bar, VIM version 8.0.642.

Comment: haha, guys, I figure it out, to equal the windows size in Mac is:

Comment: aha, guys, I figure it out, to equal the windows size in Mac is: "ctrl+option+w+=". A little complicated, but it works, for me!!

Comment: As romainl said, it should work just the same. It's a Vim command, not a OS dependent GUI thing. Just make sure you're typing the sequence correctly... it's ^W and then =. Not all together. See the help for window-resize

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. But as I post, what works for me is "ctrl+option+w+=". I am also confused, as "ctrl+w" for switching works. maybe the "=" key? in Mac, "option+=" is "≠"

Answer (score 0):

aha, guys, I figure it out, to equal the windows size in Mac is: "ctrl+option+w+=". A little complicated, but it works, for me!!
my computer is Macbookpro 2017 with touch bar, VIM version 8.0.642.